# RegEx repeating capture

Tags: javascript, regex

Can a RegEx be created to pull the same pattern over and over? 
https://regex101.com/r/BEOHLh/2/
Tried something like this too:

```
.* [(.*?)='(.*?)']{0-5}.*
```

to allow for everything in square brackets to repeat.

I could parse it without RegEx, but seem like RegEx would be the best.  I'm converting some WordPress shortcodes to a NodeJS based system. Need to extract id and label (either one may be optional), so here are three test cases and the code I tried.

```
var testArray = ["[include_word id='110']", "[include_word label='bah']", "[include_word id='987' label='bah-beh']"];

testArray.forEach (processArrayItemRegex);

function processArrayItemRegex (item, index) {
    console.log ("index:" + index + " item:" + item); 
    //var regexPattern = /.*id='(<id>.*?)'.*label='(<label>.*?)'.*/g; 
    //var regexPattern = /.*(?:id='(.*?)').*(?:label='(.*?)').*/g; 
    var regexPattern = /.* (.*?)='(.*?)'.*/g;
    //const { groups: segments } = item.match(regexPattern);
    var segments = item.match(regexPattern);
    console.dir(segments, { depth: null });
    //console.log(segments);
    id = segments[0]; 
    label = segments[1]; 
    console.log("id=" + id + " label=" + label); 
}
```

Current output:

```
index:0 item:[include_word id='110']
[ '[include_word id=\'110\']' ]
id=[include_word id='110'] label=undefined
index:1 item:[include_word label='bah']
[ '[include_word label=\'bah\']' ]
id=[include_word label='bah'] label=undefined
index:2 item:[include_word id='987' label='abc']
[ '[include_word id=\'987\' label=\'abc\']' ]
id=[include_word id='987' label='abc'] label=undefined
```

The code below works to convert it to JSON and let's me access the variables, it's just not as elegant as I would like:

```
function processArrayItem (item, index) {
    console.log ("index:" + index + " item:" + item); 
    //remove unneeded wrappers 
    item = item.replace("include_word ","")
    item = item.replace("[","{").replace("]","}");; 
    item = item.replace(/'/g, '"');
    item = item.replace('id=','"id":'); 
    item = item.replace('label=','"label":'); 
    item = item.replace('transliteration=','"transliteration"'); 
    var itemObj = JSON.parse(item); 
    console.log("id=" + itemObj.id + " label=" + itemObj.label); 
}
```

Comment: So, you want to extract everything your regex matches, correct?

Comment: AFAIK the Javascript regex engine will only keep track of the last capture, in a repeating capture group.

Comment: @VLAZ yes - if I could convert it to JSON without the word include_word that would be perfect.  I started to try that, by doing string.replace, I that might still be the easiest thing to do.  Just trying not make code flexible in case I have other WordPress shortcodes to do later.  It was putting the single quotes around the variable names that was hard-coding or tedious looping.

Comment: I added to bottom of question the way I can get it working; not difficult, just not as flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you want,

```
testArray.forEach (processArrayItemRegex);

function processArrayItemRegex (item, index) {
    console.log ("index:" + index + " item:" + item); 

    var regexPattern = /(\S+)='(\S+)'/g;
    //console.log(regexPattern);

    var id = label = 'undefined';
    var segments ;
    while ((segments  = regexPattern.exec(item)) != null)
    {
        //console.dir(segments , { depth: null });
        var key = segments [1]; 
        var value = segments [2]; 

        if (key == 'id')
            id = value;
        if (key == 'label')
            label = value;
    };
    console.log("id=" + id + " label=" + label); 
}
```

Console output:

```
index:0 item:[include_word id='110']
id=110 label=undefined
index:1 item:[include_word label='bah']
id=undefined label=bah
index:2 item:[include_word id='987' label='bah-beh']
id=987 label=bah-beh
```

Comment: Not quite: Expected output is: 1) id=110, label-undefined; 2) id=undefined, label=bah, 3) id=987 label='bah-beh'

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! Longer than I thought, but works. And still has hard-coded values though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the thing you're missing is the `matchAll` function.

Try this as a starting point:

```js
for (let match of "[include_word id='987' label='bah-beh']".matchAll(
    /(\S+)='(\S+)'/g
)) {
    console.log({ key: match[1], value: match[2] });
}
```

Comment: TypeError: "[include_word id='987' label='bah-beh']".matchAll(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: It appears to only be supported in node 12. I hadn't realised it was so recent. If that's not an option, there's an alternative listed on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Regexp.exec()_and_matchAll())

Comment: Thanks, I'm on 10.16.3, planning to run in AWS Lambda, so have to check their support.